# $f(x) = \int_0^x\frac{1-t^2}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}dt$ find it's derivative and tangent where x = 0

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

**I am given this function:**

$$f(x) = \int_0^x\frac{1-t^2}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}dt$$

I have to find it's derivative $f'(x)$ and I have to find the equation of it's tangent in the point $x = 0$. I'm a bit confused about this one.

**I think it's derivative is:** $$\frac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}$$

Is that right?

I've tried finding it's tangent, where $x = 0$.

I've found $k_t = 1$, $x_0 = 0$, $y_0 = f(0)$ and inserted this into the equation:

$$y - y_0 = k_t(x - x_0)$$
$$y = x - f(0)$$

Did I do this correctly or did I entirely miss the point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct. It is a common error to "overthink" the calculation of $f'$. One thing you left out is the evaluation of $f(0)$. What is it?

Comment: But how can I find $f(0)$? I've tried calculating the indefinite integral, but that's just too complicated.. am I not seeing something?

Comment: If you plug in 0, then you will see that the integral is going from a lower bound of 0 to an upper bound of 0. Now imagine that in terms of area.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes it equal $0$?

Comment: @NejcPisk That's right! More generally: $\int\limits_a^af(x)\,dx=0$

Answer (score 4):

i don't think you even need to take the derivative. observe that 
$$(1-t^2)((1+t^4)^{-1/2}= (1-t^2)(1-\frac{1}{2}t^4+\cdots)=1+\cdots$$
so we have 
$$f(x)= \int_0^x (1-t^2)((1+t^4)^{-1/2}\, dt = \int_0^x (1 + \cdots) \, dt = x + \cdots$$

therefore the tangent to $y = f(x)$  at $x = 0$ is the linear approximation $y = x.$